# Visual Studio - how to set auto new line

Tags: visual-studio

Where in Visual Studio do I set the option to automatically add a new line?

[image]

Comment: Hi Gohyu - if the answer provided below by @adrianbanks fixed your issue, please accept it, if for no other reason than this question is flagged as solved for other people looking for this same question/answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That isn't an automatic new line, it is showing you that the editor has word-wrapped the content onto the next line.

You can turn it off in the options in Visual Studio. To do so, go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General` (you can also do it for a specific language as well).

[image]

You currently have word wrap turned on, as well as the visual glyph (the little green arrow in your screenshot).